# highlighting is for no obvious reason

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a large script and I have extracted a few lines into two files, `why1.ksh` and `why2.ksh`, to show highlighting issue I am seeing that I can't explain.

Here are the two lines of `why1.ksh`:

```
output_string "LOG" "[`date`][${RULE_NAME}][${SOURCE_NAME}][${DEST_NAME[${DEST_INDX}]}] DEST_FLAG_FILE[${DEST_INDX}]:       ${DEST_FLAG_FILE[${DEST_INDX}]:}"
output_string "LOG" "[`date`][${RULE_NAME}][${SOURCE_NAME}][${DEST_NAME[${DEST_INDX}]}] DEST_FLAG_FILE[${DEST_INDX}]:       ${DEST_FLAG_FILE[${DEST_INDX}]:}"
```

Here's the one line of `why2.ksh`:

```
SUCCESS_EMAIL="${SUCCESS_EMAIL//,/\\n}"
```

Can any of you reproduce these problems and then tell me what is the problem?

I am using vim version 8.2.0486-1.
My syntax/vim.sh version is 189, last change October 16, 2019.

Images follow...

[image]
[image]

Here's a version of why2.ksh that shows it works for me as coded:

[image]

Comment: What is the highlighting issue you're experiencing? Note that Vim shipped a buggy `syntax/sh.vim` for a while, I think the bug was related to highlighting closing quotes... You might want to try the latest Vim (or just upgrade `syntax/sh.vim`) to see if your issue is solved there.

Comment: Also, the syntax may not know to use ksh (sometimes you have to set this), and getting shell syntax right for vim is actually quite difficult

Comment: You can post screenshots by attaching images here. See instructions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links (In short, you can drag and drop images into the edit box and they'll get attached here.)

Answer (score 1):

These are actually highlighting actual issues you have with your files.

In `why1.ksh`, the line ends with:

```
${DEST_FLAG_FILE[${DEST_INDX}]:}
```

So you have a `${parameter}` followed by a single `:`, as in `${parameter:}`, but that is not actually valid syntax in ksh or any Bourne shell. The valid operators are `:-` or `:=` or `:+` or `:?`. Bash additionally supports `:` with an offset and optional length, but you don't have an offset here either, and this is ksh. But a `:` on its own just before the `}` seems to be invalid on every shell.

See [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L488-L491) in the `syntax/sh.vim` for the recognized formats for each shell flavor:

```
" sh ksh bash : ${parameter:-word}    word is default value
" sh ksh bash : ${parameter:=word}    assign word as default value
" sh ksh bash : ${parameter:?word}    display word if parameter is null
" sh ksh bash : ${parameter:+word}    use word if parameter is not null, otherwise nothing
```

In `why2.ksh`, you're trying to use the `${parameter//pattern/string}` syntax. This *is* a valid syntax, but only for bash and not for ksh. (The syntax highlighting script for filetype `sh` detects the flavor, based on the file extension, the shebang line or some global variable settings, so it's detecting ksh in your case.)

See [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L527-L528) for the comment about this particular syntax format, in particular the comment indicating it's only recognized for the "bash" flavor.

```
 " bash : ${parameter//pattern/string}
 " bash : ${parameter//pattern}
```

Comment: One can also force a certain syntax by e.g. defining some global variables `:let g:is_bash=1` and a like, see `:h sh.vim` and scroll down a bit

Comment: On why1.ksh, good point!  That one is an easy fix!

Comment: On why2.ksh, it appears on my version of ksh that syntax is valid.  I have added an image of the working code above.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JoelBreazeale I guess the author of `syntax/sh.vim` was being strict with ksh settings, since there are actually quite a few flavors of ksh and some of them support more or fewer features... You might want to consider using `let g:is_bash = 1` in your vimrc as suggested by Christian above, this would make `syntax/sh.vim` always consider bash settings. This would assume that bash-like syntax would be OK, which I'm not sure it's really the case... Anyways, I'm not really a ksh user, so not sure what would be best here.